# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <cc-text-area> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-directives

I am making a component InputText.vue as follows:

```
    <template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Edit Text:</h4>
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Enter text here..." v-model="textBoxInput" @keyup="textChanged"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default{
        data: function(){
            return {
                textBoxInput: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            textChanged: function(){
                this.$emit('displayTextChanged', this.textBoxInput);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I am registering and using it in CardFront.vue component as follows:

```
<style>
    .edit-area {
        padding: 20px;
        height: 800px;
        background-color: #d2f9f9;
    }

    .card-display {
        padding: 20px;
        height: 800px;
    }
</style>


<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-sm-6 edit-area">
            <cc-text-area></cc-text-area>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 card-display">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import TextInput from './TextInput.vue'

    export default{
        components: {
            ccTextArea: TextInput
        }
    }
<script>
```

It gives this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gV2H.png)

Please help me out. I am using Vue version 2. Whenever I try to refresh the page, it gives error like: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Try adding `name: 'InputText', right before `export default{` in you InputText component.

Comment: Added name option but still the same issue. <script> export default{ name: "TextInput", data: function(){ return { textBoxInput: "" } }, methods: { textChanged: function(){ this.$emit('displayTextChanged', this.textBoxInput); } } } </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Thank you so much everyone for your help. The issue lied in the closing script tag in CardFront.vue component.

Comment: Next time please use the "Add a comment" feature instead of replying to the post. You can use the @ symbol to directly reply to someone using their username.

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a component InputText.vue as follows:

Check that the filename and component names match.

If you `import TextInput from './TextInput.vue'` in the using component, then also make sure you name your component that, and optionally add a `name` property as suggested in the comments.

```
// TextInput.vue (not InputText.vue)

export default {
  name: 'TextInput',
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: Checked the file name and the component name, both are same. Also added name option but still the same issue.
<script>
    export default{
        name: "TextInput",
        data: function(){
            return {
                textBoxInput: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            textChanged: function(){
                this.$emit('displayTextChanged', this.textBoxInput);
            }
        }
    }
</script>